# why object's property is undefind?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor, properties

what I want is if I did not call the object with **new** keyword then do not do this line

```
this.price = price
```

I created the constructor function and created the property **price**
and I created the object **prod1**. and I called it using **new** keyword.
I expected the output is 200 but it is **undefined**.
I want when I use new keyword to call the object print in the console 200, which is the value of the price property.

```
let Prodcut = function(price) {
    if (!new.target)
        throw this.price = price;
};

let prod1 = new Prodcut("200");
console.log(prod1.price);
```

note:

1. I saw it in a video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5wGZiYVfjk&list=PL7pEw9n3GkoW0ceMeoycg9D00YjPAbtvt&index=2&t=190s]
2. when I move

```
this.price = price
```

to the next line it is says
 "no line break is allowed between 'throw' and its expression"

Comment: Why do you expect that?

Comment: Move `this.price = price` to the next line?

Comment: @DaveNewton Because I used new keyword

Comment: @adiga it says "no line break is allowed between 'throw' and its expression"

Comment: You need to throw an error. Something like: `if (!new.target) throw "error message";
  this.price = price;`

Comment: @adiga thank you It is first time I heard about error message

Comment: It's just a string. You can throw any expression or Error object you like. `throw "use new keyword"` or `throw new Error('use new keyword')`

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to check if you constructor has been called with the keyword `new` I think the condition should change. because you are putting that property if the constructor is called without it. You may try this

```js
let Prodcut = function(price) {
    if (new.target)
        this.price = price;
};

let prod1 = new Prodcut("200");
console.log(prod1.price);
```

Comment: It is a good solution but I saw the code in a video and trying to do like the video

Comment: Also, don't take everything form videos, or the internet, at face value. Not all videos are reputable. Some that are, have errors or tips. Not all mistakes get fixed, due to the nature of videos. That said, is is good you're asking questions, and reproducing the code on your own. The most important, though, is learning to understand code, troubleshooting, and it's fine to find alternate ways of achieving the same end goal.

Comment: @SherylHohman I know I don't have to take everything from videos but I was confused why It is not the same output